# Two for loops take lot of time for execution any solution to reduce time JAVA

Tags: java

This is my data in java it will take lot of time for processing and getting response if data is huge how to optimize this code for getting fast action

```
List<EventLog> eventLogs = new ArrayList<EventLog>();
List<EventLog> eventLogData = get(currentUser, data);
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (EventLog rep : eventLogData) {
    if (map.containsKey(rep.getEventType())) {
    map.put(rep.getEventType(), map.get(rep.getEventType()) + 1);
    } else {
    map.put(rep.getEventType(), 1);
    }
}

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    EventLog list = new EventLog();
    list.setEventType(entry.getKey());
    list.setCount(entry.getValue());
    eventLogs.add(list);
}

return eventLogs;
```

Comment: "Huge" and "long time" are not very specific.  Please elaborate.

Comment: both run in linear time (are only one level deep), there is probably nothing you can do unless you specify in more detail what the desired outcome is and in what way the loops are too slow.

Comment: Have you profiled your application?  Are you certain that this is the block of code where a lot of execution time is occuring?  Are you certain that this block would benefit from optimization?

Comment: It seems so difficult to optimize this part of code, maybe when we can see a bigger part we can have a better imagination. Perhaps, in the sometimes, we can use another approach, like Arrays, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an alternative high performance collections library?
Here is my implementation, using the [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) library. It provides a much faster execution since

1. The map is update requires a single access (adjustOrPutValue) instead of the two in the original implementation (containsKey and get)
2. It handle primitive int's instead of Integer's and avoids all the boxing and unboxing operations, and consumes less memory

.

```
List<EventLog> eventLogData = get(currentUser, data);
TObjectIntMap<String> map = new TObjectIntHashMap<>();

for (EventLog rep : eventLogData) {
    map.adjustOrPutValue(rep.getEventType(), 1, 1);
}

List<EventLog> eventLogs = new ArrayList<>();
map.forEachEntry(new TObjectIntProcedure<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String key, int value) {
        EventLog list = new EventLog();
        list.setEventType(key);
        list.setCount(value);
        eventLogs.add(list);
        return true;
    }
});

return eventLogs;
```

Answer (score -6):

Modify your code in one loop like this you can use for instead of `foreach` loop get the size of list using `list.size()`:

```
for(int a=0, b=5 ; a<=5 ; a++,b--){
    // do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Do you even understand what the code in the question is doing? It's doing a group-by with counter.

Comment: @Muhammad Waqas Can you update your code Sir in my code I am using mongodb as back end